# helm Traverse the list value of yaml files

Tags: kubernetes-helm

## value.yml

```yaml
age:
  - 22
  - 36
```

## configMap

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: myapp-config
data:
toppings:
{{- range $topping := $.Values.setAge }}
 - {{ $topping }}
{{- end }}
```

## command

```bash
helm template production --set setName=age /opt/shell/helm/helm-jar/
```

## output

```bash
<$.Values.setAge>: range can't iterate over age
```

I want to dynamically pass parameters through -- set,
Then read the content of the value.yml file

## Expected results

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: myapp-config
data:
toppings:
  - 18
  - 36
```

Comment: You need to use the `index` function; `index .Values .Values.setAge` will provide you the dictionary in `values.yaml` under the key named by `setAge`.

Comment: Often I see this setup for per-environment settings, and if this pattern only appears once, also consider whether `helm install -f age.yaml ...` with a separate values file per environment would be easier than writing this lookup into code.